# How the user[age] is "not defined" (error) here, Whereas the user[name] is defined?

Tags: javascript

```js
function User(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var user = new User('Daniel', 45);
document.write(user[name] + ' ' + 'is' + ' ' + user[age] + ' ' + 'years old!');
```

the user[age] throws error saying

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `age` is not defined

whereas `user[name]` works fine

Comment: I think you meant `user['name']` and `user['age']`

Answer (score 1):

`user[name]` doesn't throw an error because it is referring to **[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)**. But, there is no `age` property in `window`. So, you get the error

To [access the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) of `user` object, you need to use dot notation or the bracket notation (with quotes):

```
user.name
user["name"]
```

Here's the updated snippet:

```js
function User(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var user = new User('Daniel', 45);
document.write(user["name"] + ' ' + 'is' + ' ' + user["age"] + ' ' + 'years old!');
```

Comment: user.name is the idomatic way in javascript an should be preferred

Answer (score 0):

You missed the string quotation.

```js
function User(name,age){
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}
var user = new User('Daniel',45);
document.write(user['name'] + ' ' + 'is' + ' '+user['age'] + ' ' + 'years old!');
```

Alternatively you can access using `.` operator like

```
document.write(user.name + ' ' + 'is' + ' ' + user.age + ' ' + 'years old!');
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to access the property as a string. It won't work if you try to access it like that.

`user[age]` is undefined while `user['age']` will return the element associated with that property. This is called bracket notation.

Notice that when you accessing properties with the `.` notation, then you don't use a string. You simply use `obj.propertyName`.

There are some cases where you don't have a choice and you must use the first approach. For example, if there are spaces in your property names, the bracket notation is the only approach that will work. See something like `obj.property name` will not access the property you want because there is a space. Here, you must use 'obj['property name']'

Answer (score -1):

There are two things in your question to be addressed

1. You are using properties of user as variables while you should use them as strings.

   document.write(user['name'] + ' ' + 'is' + ' '+user['age'] + ' ' + 'years old!');
2. Secondly, its not throwing error for name while it is for age because the window already has a property/ variable name which has value "".Try below on browser console.

   window.name

Comment: Please don't repeat what other answers have already mentioned